# How to compare one dataframe with another and check whether the same data in first df present in second df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

have two df.both df's with one column and same names

df1 have 40000 rows and df 2 have 80000 rows.

How to compare whether the data in df1 is same as of df2.

Expected output :  any message stating that 40000 rows in df1 matched with df2 which has 80000 rows

```
40000 items in df1 matched with 80000 items in df2
```

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Comment: sure will do that

Comment: @hukkemaaru You need Matched Columns or just the message

Comment: if possible both else matched columns will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
m = df1['c'] == df2['c']
print('{0:d} items in df1 matched with {1:d} items in df2'.format(sum(m), len(m)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
match = df1[df1['column name'].isin(df2['column name'])].shape[0]


print(('%.i items matched') % match)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 matches = (df2 == df1).stack()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['A'])
df
    A
0  10
1  15
2  14
3  20
4  25
5  26

 df2
    A
0  10
1  15
2  14
3  20
4  25
5  26
6  30
7  32
8  34
9  36



df2[df2.A.isin(df.A.values)]
    A
0  10
1  15
2  14
3  20
4  25
5  26
```

Matched element

Comment: this is giving unmatched data i guess.

Comment: @hukkemaaruspetus I am sure this return matched while `df2[~df2.A.isin(df.A.values)]` return unmatched data